# Python login with requests library

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, postman

After a whole day of searching, I unfortunately did not succeed.
I would like to create a script who login and fill a form with python (i'm using the requests library).
If i resume my problem i just would like to do a POST requete from Postman for example for this form, but it's allways give me a 500 error, even i copie all the Request header and all the Resquest payload... I don't understand why.
My dream to give a 400 error :D
(I made a summary here but it's been all day since I tried to achieve it.)
The url : https://wallet.esw.esante.gouv.fr/auth/?response_type=code&scope=openid%20identity&client_id=portail-ecps&state=0t0YIzB4ar33dpuU5IK1yN8v6t8&redirect_uri=https:%2F%2Fwallet.esw.esante.gouv.fr%2Fredirect_uri&nonce=0KbgFrUIWvR-mrU63ZX6aViGEWz1tSnlGEP0XE4ZiFQ&acr_values=eidas2

Answer (score 0):

Stop running javascript on your browser and try to get page source then you will have gotten nothing. Request module is not good with javascrip websites. Take a look for selenium